# minimax code returns always 0

Tags: java, numbers, artificial-intelligence, minimax, alpha-beta-pruning

I wrote an Alpha-Beta pruning from Wikipedia. I am trying to write a connect-four AI. The function should return column number, then my main function makes a move.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is in this line I believe:

```
if(temp[i][column-1] == '0')
```

`temp` is an int array. You should compare just `0`. `'0'` means the character 0, which Java will interpret as an integer (48). Anyways, you should use this:

```
if(temp[i][column-1] == 0)
```

Comment: I would go a step farther, this code have never compiled.

Comment: That's right, java and it's type safe features... Edited appropriately.

Comment: Java will actually let you do direct comparisons/assignments between ints and chars because chars are really just ints interpreted in a special way. See the Character class javadocs for details.  Btw, I'm not saying your answer is wrong on the whole, just pointing out that small mistake.

Comment: code is working now but it's returns column number only 1 and 2. is this problem in minimax or my evalution function?